# Using Codeigniter framework to connect to DSN

Tags: php, codeigniter, odbc

i'm using the Codeigniter framework to try and connect to an foxpro db, i have created a system dsn

here s my codeignighter config

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => 'test',
'hostname' => '10.0.0.3',
'username' => '',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'Live2',
'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

when i try to connect i get the following error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect

Filename: odbc/odbc_driver.php

any ideas where i could be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

odbc_connect needs also a setup in odbc data source administrator.

you need to setup a driver in [odbc data source admin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716327(v=vs.85).aspx)
and give your hostname the driver name and ip.

(you need to install on your server an ODBC driver for the specific DB you are using, for example [oracle sql odbc driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html))

```
'hostname'=>"Driver={Driver as defined in ODBC};Server=10.0.0.3"
```

Comment: Thank Daniel that worked, now im getting The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'users' even though the users table exists